# Formatting numeric fields in attribute table in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

In ArcGIS you have the following window that allows you to visualize your numeric values in your attribute table in a diffrent manner. (Sorry the Image is in German)

[image]

In the example numeric values will be rounded to the 3rd decimal number and the alignment will be left. This does **not** change the data, it is simply represented differently in the attribute table. in ArcGIS you could also set the settings to show the data in scientific style or in fractions

I would love to do this in QGIS as well. To tell QGIS to represent the data with a max of 2 decimal numbers but actually use all decimal numbers when computing.

Is this somehow possible?

I'm using QGIS 3.4.13

Comment: which attribute table do you want to reformat? in the print layout you can apply any function you like (e.g. round() )

Comment: I mean the attribute table in the project window

Answer (score 2):

You're able to display not the original column but a **virtual field** based on your original colum and then use something like the following :

```
round(my_column[,places=0])
```

Comment: hmm yes that would sort of work but its not nice to create a new field, eventhough its just virtual. There is no handier way?